# Cannot read property 'value' of null?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am getting error when I try to use `this.username.value`. I want to get value of textbox to show in label. I am newbie to react. How to get value from Textbox to a variable and display in Label using InputRef.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import TextBox from 'components/Atoms/TextBox';
import makeSelectTestPage from './selectors';

export class TestPage extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.username ='',
    this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this);
  }
  handelChange() {
    console.log("Log",this.username.value);
    <label> this.username.value</label>
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet
          title="TestPage"
          meta={[
            { name: 'description', content: 'Description of TestPage' },
          ]}
        />
        <TextBox labelName="Input Vaue" placeholder="Test" ref={(inputRef) => { this.username = inputRef; }} defaultValue="Text" ></TextBox>
        <button onClick={this.handelChange}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TestPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  TestPage: makeSelectTestPage(),
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TestPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question there are a few mistakes. Try to understand the next code and your will be able to apply it to your example :

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
   
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
      value: "",
      username: ""
    }
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({username: this.state.value})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.state.username}</label><br />
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}></input><br />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Login</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2879/)